# Blazor - ClosedXml - excel cannot open the file beacause the file format or extension is not valid

Tags: excel, blazor, blazor-server-side, closedxml

I'm trying to download some data from my blazor page to an excel workbook.
When I try to open the file however I get the following error message :

*excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid*

When I open the file in notepad++ I get see a bunch of letters and signs but no valid data.
[image]

This is my code:

```
 public byte[] SaveSearchToExcel(List<EquipmentForm> EquipmentForms)
    {
        var wb = new XLWorkbook();
  

        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Search Results");
        ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "TLV Number";
        ws.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Descirption";
        for(int row = 0; row < EquipmentForms.Count; row++)
        {
            ws.Cell(row + 1, 1).Value = EquipmentForms[row].TLVNumber;
            ws.Cell(row+1, 2).Value = EquipmentForms[row].Description;
        }



        MemoryStream XLSStream = new();
        wb.SaveAs(XLSStream);
        XLSStream.Position = 0;
        return XLSStream.ToArray();

    }

  private async void SaveToExcel(){
    var XLSStream= _saveToExcel.SaveSearchToExcel(EquipmentForms);
    
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorDownloadFile", "export.xlsx",Convert.ToBase64String(XLSStream));

    }

function BlazorDownloadFile(filename, content) {
// thanks to Geral Barre : https://www.meziantou.net/generating-and-downloading-a-file-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm 

// Create the URL
const file = new File([content], filename, { type: "application/octet-stream" });
const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

// Create the <a> element and click on it
const a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.href = exportUrl;
a.download = filename;
a.target = "_self";
a.click();

// We don't need to keep the object url, let's release the memory
// On Safari it seems you need to comment this line... (please let me know if you know why)
URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
```

}

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Thx for the help!
Sarah

EDIT:
Changed the following code: And this works now.

```
function BlazorDownloadFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: You should download the `byte[]` not a Base64 encoded string ;)

Comment: Tried the following:  private async void SaveToExcel(){
        byte[] XLSStream= _saveToExcel.SaveSearchToExcel(EquipmentForms);
        
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorDownloadFile", "export.xlsx",XLSStream);

        } still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Changed the folowing code:

```
function BlazorDownloadFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = filename;
link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

}

Works now :)